# Asp.Net MVC - Globally restrict request duration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I set the maximum duration of any kind of request to, lets say 5 seconds?

I have tried setting the `httpRuntime executionTimeout` on the `system.web` section without any luck (yes, i even published to my azure and checked that the `debug` is not present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead set [HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.scripttimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) to the desired timeout value. Despite the name, this is a per-request setting and should apply to any ASP.NET request.

This time-out applies only if the `debug` attribute in the `compilation` element is `False`. In web.config (when set to `"debug=true"` mode, the runtime will ignore the timeout setting):

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" />
```

But notice that the `executionTimeout` will still has some delay when the value is very small. In fact, it is recommended that we don't set the timeout less than 1.5 minutes. And when we set the timeout to less than 1 minute, the delay will span from 5 secs up to 15 secs. For example, if we set `executionTimeout="5"`, it may take a bout 15 seconds for the page to timeout.

Comment: well that won't cut it... i intend to set 10 sec timeout... it's better than nothing but i need something more reliable than that...

Comment: the remarks on that reference says "The ScriptTimeout property can be set in the Web.config file by setting the executionTimeout attribute of the element. Setting the time-out programmatically with the ScriptTimeout property takes precedence over the Web.config setting." so i don't think it will work, but i will try anyway...